# Mixing CPVC sizes through a heater

Tags: water-heater

I am off grid, and need more hot water pressure.
When they built my house they plumbed 1/2 inch CPVC to two showers, 3 sinks and a washer.
The reason is the hot water heater has 1/2 inch in and out, fed by 3/4 inch cold water line.
So I am thinking to run 3/4 CPVC as a main line then use the 1/2 drop to each fixture.
But not sure if the pressure is going to increase as the longest run is 30 feet.
Current pressure is 50-30lbs on my tank
Thoughts & thanks

---

It is a tankless heater, "china" its all we can get here. I am getting ready to replace it as it has lost heat ability now that it is 6yrs old. Water is rain water that is filtered, almost no mineral content as tested. the kitchen is the shortest run, and is ok but with the 90's as it winds under the house there is loss. and I am planning on coming out of the heater with a 1/2 to 3/4 reducer, then 6 feet to a T one run of 30' then a 3/4 to 1/2 90 feeding the far bath shower and sink. the other side of the T would feed the kitchen and other bath & washer with a 3/4 to 1/2 90 at each feed.

Heater has 1/2 inch in and 1/2 out!

Comment: Are you sure about needing more pressure, 50lbs is usually enough for most people?  Maybe you want more volume or amount of of hot water?  Larger pipes will increase amount of flow.

Comment: **1/2" is unusual for a water heater intended for more than a single point of use.** You'd improve the pressure lost to the piping (dynamic head) somewhat, as you're only restricting to 1/2" at the ports in and out of the tank itself, rather than on the 30 foot run, but there might be other issues - *i.e.* if it's a tankless heater that's in need of cleaning, and has high flow resistance internally because of that, changing pipe size might not help noticeably. Please [edit] to include more details about your system, particularly since off-grid systems are sometimes unusual.

Comment: If you have a 3/4" inlet and it is not reduced to 1/2" to get connected to the heater, I am surprised it is not a 3/4" on the outlet. Unless it is a 1/2" on both lines. On demand heaters are rated, that I am aware of based on climate, how many fixtures it can serve running continuously. Is yours rated in that fashion? It starts how warm/cold the water is going into the system. There is a region chart associated with this too. Mine is sized based on 1 shower and a faucet running continuously. It is 3/4" in and out. The reason I bring this up is, it may be "throttled down" with the smaller pipe.

Comment: Maybe you should share pics or the model number of the water heater. My guess is that you have a small tankless unit that is meant to be used with only single faucets. If this is the case then replacing the piping might only have negligible benefit. Those heaters are designed to restrict water flow so that it can be warmed up sufficiently. To get better flow you would need to replace it with a bigger unit that can heat up more water per minute. You might also benefit from using a booster pump for increasing the flow of water.